# Excel average of previous days

Tags: excel, excel-formula, moving-average

Is there an option in an Excel table to calculate average data of previous days?

Preview of Excel:

[image]

I'm looking for a formula like `=average (([Production]:[Production]8 days before)` so I can copy it to the entire table:

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could there be a gap in the dates? If there is, do you still need the average or actually the sum divided by 8? (That is, a production of 0 for missing dates).

Answer (score 1):

If by 8 days before you can just use the previous 8 rows, you can do as simple as this:

For cell C9 (Jan 8th):

```
=AVERAGE(B2:B9)
```

And then copy that to the cells below. For the cells when you don't have 8 values, you will need to manually reduce the range (always starting in B2).

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula-

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$16,$A$2:$A$16,"<="&A2,$A$2:$A$16,">="&A2-7)/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$16,"<="&A2,$A$2:$A$16,">="&A2-7)
```

[image]

If it is table then use formula like-

```
=SUMIFS([Production],[Date],"<="&A2,[Date],">="&A2-7)/COUNTIFS([Date],"<="&A2,[Date],">="&A2-7)
```

If you have Excel365 then use `AVERAGEIFS()` formula.

```
=AVERAGEIFS([Production],[Date],"<="&A2,[Date],">="&A2-7)
```